# Can humans use god ki?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super, Battle of Gods and Resurrection 'F', gods of destruction, beings belonging to Whiss's race (some sort of angels or angels), supreme kais and super saiyan gods can use "god ki". In DBS and Resurrection 'F' also, others no super saiyan gods saiyans like Vegeta can obtain the power of god ki without transforming into super saiyan god by training (and also becoming super saiyan god super saiyan by transforming) . Can other Dragon Ball races like humans or namekians or  Frost Demons obtain god ki by training too?

Comment: Well its all based on speculation but i would say yes, however if we look back at the gap between saiyans and the other races its questionable if they will ever reach the required level to activate the god ki. We could get a hint from fighters from another universe though, if they are capable of fighting goku then they also have the potential to activate god ki (or should have it). In the end, these are all speculation, maybe super will give some more hints as it progresses.

Comment: @Proxy Hit might have the possibility.

Comment: @HappyFace yeah, he is so far the most likely candidate but his fighting style is a bit different but we will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply **yes**, not only humans, all mortals could obtain or use god ki via various ways:

1. Through special rituals, such as Super Saiyan God Ritual. Unfortunately this kind of rituals don't exist throughout human history, but maybe it do exist in other races.
2. Highly intense training under the supervision of an angel, for example Whis. It's most likely to obtain god ki by entering the Hyperbolic Time Chamber.

[(Source)](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ki#Deities)

Comment: do you think we will ever see a human learning to use god ki in Dragon Ball Super?

Comment: without a major external power up, i would say no. The humans from the Z warriors are nowhere near the level goku and vegeta are. Maybe some humans from another universe are strong enough to achieve it though.

Comment: @Pablo I think that it's plausible if Super extends beyond the world tournament arc of Dragon Ball Z. IIRC. Goku basically takes on Uub as his disciple and trains him to be the new protector of earth. So if Super reaches that far. I'm sure Uub could reach god ki status. But that's a big if.

Comment: @KazRodgers you know, I was just thinking about Buu too. He was in the level of Goku in base form being a kid. There might be another candidates though. Tien was able to hold his own against Trunks in base form, in the movie just after Goku died, and many years has passed from that. He might be in the level of some super saiyans (like the kids or Cabbe) or an android by now

Comment: By the way, even Yamcha was able to overpower Olibu and another fighter, and Olibu made a decent fight against Paikuhan, who gave enormous trouble to Goku SSJ